# Real body height in Firefox Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, firefox, mobile

I need to create block with fixed width and fixed height dinamically (with javascript). Width needs to be a 100% of document body width, and height needs to be a 100% of document body height. In other browsers all is fine, but Firefox Mobile have a top bar (wich I belive have affect on height of document), so all height calculations on document loading are wrong. When I scrolling page down this top bar hides, and I can see height of my block is shorten then I need...
Is there any solution? Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
$(window).width();
$(window).height();
```

Should work.

Comment: thank you for tryin' to help me, but I use precisely this method! But you know what... it looks like Mozilla guys fix this bug! I just tested my code after Firefox last update, and didn't get this bug anymore.